# Cannot convert from "Surface_mesh" to "Nef_polyhedron_3"

Tags: c++, cgal

## Issue

I loaded my own mesh file (.obj) which is creadted by "CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::extrude_mesh()". I want to use the"Nef_polyhedron_3()" to convert my Surface_mesh object into a Nef_polyhedron_3 object. The code fails to compile, and I get some errors like these:

```
C2440 "Initialize": Cannot convert from "_Ty" to "size_t"   polygon_mesh_to_nef_3.h 199
C2440 "Initialize": Cannot convert from "_Ty" to "size_t"   polygon_mesh_to_nef_3.h 250
C2440 "Initialize": Cannot convert from "_Ty" to "size_t"   polygon_mesh_to_nef_3.h 282
```

## Source Code

```
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel  Kernel;
typedef Kernel::Point_3 Point;
typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh<Point> SM;
typedef Kernel::Vector_3 Vector;
typedef boost::graph_traits<SM>::face_descriptor        face_descriptor;
typedef boost::graph_traits<SM>::halfedge_descriptor      halfedge_descriptor;
typedef SM::Property_map<face_descriptor, Vector>             FaceMap;
typedef SM::Property_map<halfedge_descriptor, Vector>             halfedgeMap;
using namespace std;
namespace PMP = CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing;
namespace params = CGAL::parameters;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        char final[] = "E:/point/output/0_10_small_final.obj";
        SM mesh;
    FaceMap faceMap;
    halfedgeMap HalMap;
    CGAL::IO::read_polygon_mesh(final, mesh);
    Nef_PHD mesh3(mesh, HalMap, faceMap);
    cout << mesh3 << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

## Environment

- Operating system (Windows/Mac/Linux, 32/64 bits): Windows 64 bits
- Compiler: Visual Studio 2019
- Release or debug mode: debug Specific
- CGAL version: 5.5.1
- Boost version: 1.71.0
- Other libraries versions if used (Eigen, TBB, etc.): Eigen 3

I want to be able to use the "Nef_polyhedron_3()" to convert my Surface_mesh object into a Nef_polyhedron_3 object, and then I can do some Boolean operations on Nef Polyhedra.
if my data(.obj) are needed, I can provide it using "Wetransfer".

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#include <CGAL/Nef_polyhedron_3.h>
typedef CGAL::Nef_polyhedron_3<K> Nef3; // K is your kernel
Nef3 nef(mesh); // convert mesh to nef
```

Comment: https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/master/Nef_3/examples/Nef_3/surface_mesh_to_nef.cpp. I was looking at this example and trying to compare your answer. Would you mind reviewing it ?

Comment: @Soundararajan This is the code I use in my program and it works fine.

Comment: thanks！ I will try to use it. the reason why I have this question is that my code mainly refers the API description, and it requires these parameters.